# How do I create my LOCO?

Tags: community, locoteams

I went to the Ubuntu website, and looked up the local area user group (LOCO) for Maine, USA, North America... it doesn't exist, but I would like it to exist.

How do I create it? how do I create an Ubuntu Local Community?

http://loco.ubuntu.com/teams/ubuntu-maineiacs/

I have a group of guys, we meet up on a bi-weekly basis. Coding, hacking (not the evil sort) and Maker projects are standard fair.

Comment: My state has a link on the ubuntu page, but it doesnt exist. isnt active, or ...?

Comment: If a LoCo team already existed, first try to contact the people who had been running it. Maybe they're not able to be active anymore and would gladly let you take over the responsibility of running it.

If you care unsuccessful in contacting that team, then you can ask the LoCo Council to make your the new owner of it.